# ExpressCheckout create payment add custom field

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

In the old-style `html` form payment create there was an extra field called `custom` and I could use it to recognize the payment after Paypal callback.  In Rest API when I'm creating a payment in Express Checkout, I want to use it but I don't see that parameter in the documentation.  There is a `custom` field in an IPN simulator but I don't know how to set it in API call.

Answer (score 1):

The custom would go in the transaction object

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#definition-transaction

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted as this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the REST API is simply still a long ways behind the Classic API with the features it provides.

For now, if you want to utilize the custom parameter (and many other nice features) you'll need to use the [classic Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/overview-ec/).

If you happen to be working with PHP check out my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It will make the Express Checkout calls very simple for you.

Answer (score 0):

Rest Api allows you to set one customer field using transaction.custom

Java SDK example in groovy

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction()
transaction.amount = new Amount("USD", "100")
transaction.custom = "xyz"

Payment payment = new Payment()
payment.transactions = [transaction]
```